# Spring security additional rights on some entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, acl

we have implemented a web application and use spring's pre-post-annotations to secure the access to some rights.

At the moment it is quite simple. We have companies. You can have read/write/admin permission on a company.

```
public class Company {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

So we have the database tables user, company and of course the spring security tables acl_class, acl_entry, acl_object_identity and acl_sid.

Now there are special entities underlying a company, let's say this is the employee.

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Company company;
}
```

One company can have many employees and a employee can only be employed at one company.

Now not every user may have read/right access onto a employee. The user must have a read/write/admin right to a company AND has to have a special right to read/write/admin the employee. So it is possible a user can have a write permission to company X but not even read access to company X's employees.
A user may have only read access to company Y and write access to all employees of company Y.

There shall be no further limitations on specific employees. Just all employees of one company.

I actually don't want to manage dynamically all acl objects for every employee but be a little more dynamic. I'm thinking of something like a "permission flag", extending a base permission on a company-permission.
Do you have an idea how I could solve this most elegant and easy?

I didn't find a good example in the spring security documentation. Is this a bad practice?

Thanks a lot for help :-)

Comment: Give your Employee a groupList and a roleList, so you can give them permissions depending on your needs.

Comment: Hey @MuratK. thanks for the quick comment but I'm sorry I don't understand. What exactly do you mean with groupList and roleList? Do you have any link or so showing the concept?

Comment: Basically that is what you suggested with permission flags. You can take it a step further and give mulitple flags e.g. Role.ADMIN, Role.SuperUser , Group.SubCompany etc. etc. [See here](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/blog/spring-security-with-roles-and-rights). Also you can google for spring role and group permissions

Comment: Can't you put a security check on the getEmployees method?

Comment: I can. The access to employees will be only possible with a spring service like service.getEmployeesOfCompany(Company c). That's where I want to secure the access..... @MuratK. Ah thanks, we already use the role-permission "pattern". I think my problem currently is the class of the table acl_class. Well, time to dig deeper :-)